# docker swarm with compose file does not recognize "links"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  hello:
    image: dockercloud/hello-world

  service_auth:
    image: beevelop/nginx-basic-auth
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - hello:web
    environment:
      HTPASSWD: 'foo:$apr1$odHl5EJN$KbxMfo86Qdve2FH4owePn.'
```

**docker --version**

```
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
```

**docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml auth**

```
Ignoring unsupported options: links
```

**Why is *links* not supported?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#not-supported-for-docker-stack-deploy) does list what is not supported for compose and stack, and that includes **[links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)**.

> Links are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name. (See also, the [Links topic in Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links).)

Hence that option is [ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/) with a (version 3) Compose file.

```
$ docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml vossibility

Ignoring unsupported options: links
```

So: *why* the option is not supported?

Because `links` are not needed in a compose scenario, since all services can already communicate one with another (being in the same network set up by compose).

Comment: The question was _why_ that option is ignored.

Comment: @alexbusu I have edited the answer to add the "why" part.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need links starting with version 2 of Compose files. Before v2, you needed to be explicit on what talked to what. In v2+, all containers on the same overlay or custom bridge network will be able to access all listening ports of other containers via their service name as DNS hostname.